# Postfix Admin Notifications - Will it trigger spam?

Tags: spam-prevention

I have successfully setup Postfix with SPF and DKIM using Google Apps (paid account with custom domain).

Before SPF and DKIM, the admin notifications ended up in spam folder but after setting those up, the emails go to my inbox (without even whitelisting the domain!)

Now, I am using tools like OSSEC which send a lot of admin notifications per day. These are only send to my own personal email address.

Is this going to affect the spam rating of my domain in the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as from my personal experience I would be quite self convinced in such situation that sending such admin notification shouldn't affect your sender reputation. As far as SPF and DKIM are properly configured and you still sending to your own address only it must not have any negative effect.